# How To Skip Functions?

Tags: python, function

I have this piece of code below. When / If the program arrives at the `if` statement: `if stocklevel < 1:`, I need to move straight to the `repeat` function.

```
def checkstocklevel(code):
with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        if code in line:
            data = line.split(",")
            stocklevel = int(data[1])
            if stocklevel < 1:
                print("Sorry, this product is out of stock")
                f = open("receipts","a")
                f.write(code)
                f.write(" Product Out Of Stock\n")
                f.close()
                repeat(username)
            elif stocklevel <= 5:
                print("New Order Required - Remaining Stock:",data[1],)
            elif stocklevel <= 10:
                print("Low Stock - Remaining Stock:",data[1],)
            else:
                print("Normal Stock -",data[1],)
            return stocklevel
```

If I add `repeat(username)` to the bottom of the above code, I arrive at the `repeat` function, but then end up back at `quantityFunction` (the step after the function above)

This is the main code sending me places;

```
while repeatchoice == True:
    code = getproductcode()
    product = checkfile(code)
    stocklevel = checkstocklevel(code)
    quantity = quantityFunction(product)
    checkquantity = isquantityokay(quantity, stocklevel)
    quantity = int(quantity)
    update = updatestocklevel(quantity, stocklevel, code)
    cost = price(product)
    productcost = calculateproductcost(cost, quantity)
    rline = receiptline(product, quantity, productcost)
    addtoreceipt = append(rline)
    addtototal = appendprice(productcost)
    repeatchoice = repeat(username)
```

Is there a way I can skip everything from `quantityFunction` to `addtototal` when I reach the `if` statement?

Comment: Which function does the first code belong to and what return value does it give to your main loop? Very unclear atm.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is... Can't you just put a `if` statement in the `while` loop, and check for stocklevel > 1 ?

Comment: I'd say either make `repeatChice` global and update it in your functions or handle your return values better, as of now only one function impacts the main loop.

Comment: How do your two pieces of code relate to each other?

Comment: It would be great, when you worry about program flow, to offer 1 uncut code snippet large enough to have all the hoops you need to describe the problem you observe, and we can than more easily understand what the intended flow was and offer our knowledge in python coding to solve your problem.

Comment: Please see edits to question. The first bit of code is inside the `checkstocklevel(code)` function

Comment: Regarding your edits. The first `if` in the function is `if code in line:`.

Comment: Whoops. Edited again @martineau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let your `checkstockLevel` function (which I'm guessing the first code snippet is from) return a boolean value (maybe in addition to what it is already returning) and then work with that. So something like this:

```
def checkstocklevel(socklevel):
    #maybe do something (I don't know if there is more code in your function)
    if stocklevel < 1:
        print("Sorry, this product is out of stock")
        f = open("receipts","a")
        f.write(code)
        f.write(" Product Out Of Stock\n")
        f.close()
        return False,stocklevel
    #...
    return True,stocklevel
```

and then in your main code do:

```
while repeatchoice == True:
    code = getproductcode()
    product = checkfile(code)
    result,stocklevel = checkstocklevel(code)
    if result:
        quantity = quantityFunction(product)
        checkquantity = isquantityokay(quantity, stocklevel)
        quantity = int(quantity)
        update = updatestocklevel(quantity, stocklevel, code)
        cost = price(product)
        productcost = calculateproductcost(cost, quantity)
        rline = receiptline(product, quantity, productcost)
        addtoreceipt = append(rline)
        addtototal = appendprice(productcost)
    repeatchoice = repeat(username)
```

Edit: Now that you added your actual function it would have to look like this:

```
def checkstocklevel(code):
    with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
        for line in f:
            if code in line:
                data = line.split(",")
                stocklevel = int(data[1])
                if stocklevel < 1:
                    print("Sorry, this product is out of stock")
                    f = open("receipts","a")
                    f.write(code)
                    f.write(" Product Out Of Stock\n")
                    f.close()
                    return False,stocklevel
                elif stocklevel <= 5:
                    print("New Order Required - Remaining Stock:",data[1],)
                elif stocklevel <= 10:
                    print("Low Stock - Remaining Stock:",data[1],)
                else:
                    print("Normal Stock -",data[1],)
                return True,stocklevel
```

Comment: Hi @Keiwan, I am needing to do a similar thing on another function I now have. I will need to skip functions like in this question. Because I already have an if 'result' in my code, will I be able to use the same method? Is result global, or could I use something like result2?

Comment: If the while loop isn't inside of a function then yes, `result` will be global. You can reassign it though, or use a `result2`, however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change your design a bit. You're telling the code to run each of the steps no matter what, so after the repeat function ends the code will still perform all the other steps. One way to fix this is to move the stock level if statement out of the function, ie:

```
while repeatchoice == True:
    code = getproductcode()
    product = checkfile(code)
    stocklevel = checkstocklevel(code)
    if stocklevel < 1:
        quantity = quantityFunction(product)
        checkquantity = isquantityokay(quantity, stocklevel)
        quantity = int(quantity)
        update = updatestocklevel(quantity, stocklevel, code)
        cost = price(product)
        productcost = calculateproductcost(cost, quantity)
        rline = receiptline(product, quantity, productcost)
        addtoreceipt = append(rline)
        addtototal = appendprice(productcost)
    repeatchoice = repeat(username)
```

And delete the call to 'repeat' in the stocklevel function.

This is ugly and it would be difficult to add more conditions, so you may want to start looking into refactoring this to use classes / object oriented programming

Comment: `if stocklevel < 1` I want to skip all the code you have put underneath it, not run through it

Comment: Then just flip it to stocklevel >= 1

Comment: What about the other if statements in the function? What do I do about these?

Comment: You can keep them in. All the code in your function will run, but after it's finished it will evaluate the return value. If the return value is less than 1, it will go straight to repeatchoice and skip the other code. If it's greater, it will run all the code, and also print the statements in your function. Just remove this line from the checkstocklevel function: repeat(username)